# What is the best way to write Bangla in latex?

Tags: fontspec

I planning to write a long report (~300 pages) in latex. My report will contain a lot of Bangla text along with English text. I found several ways to write Bangla in latex, but I failed to choose the best way.

Another `important` thing is that when I use Bangla setting as *main font*, it changes the *font face* of default English font of latex. I used the command:

```
\setmainfont{[Kalpurush]}
```

I showed this differences in the figures. In figure 1, before setting the Bangla as main font. In figure 2, after setting the Bangla as main font. I don't want this change, is it possible to keep the same font face? It may be visual change, how to avoid this?

[image]

Figure 1: Before setting Bangla as main font

[image]

Figure 2: After setting Bangla as main font

So, I want to know the best way of using Bangla in latex without changing the default English font face. How can I do that?

I want both English and Bangla fonts. Latin Computer Modern as English font and Kalpurush as Bangla font.

Comment: Incidentally, what *is* your preferred main text font? Latin Modern? Something else?

Comment: I want both English and Bangla fonts. Latin Computer Modern as English font and Kalpurush as Bangla font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `lualatex` and `english` as the main language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}

\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

Let’s write a short English text, and then a Bangla one (from the
Wikipedia): বাংলা ভাষা বিকাশের ইতিহাস ১৩০০ বছর পুরনো। চর্যাপদ এ ভাষার
আদি নিদর্শন.

\end{document}
```

[image]
See also [the page on Bangla in the `babel` site](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-bengali.html).

Comment: If I want to use `Kalpurush` font for Bangla type setting?

Comment: @Masudur - Then, just replace `FreeSerif` with `Kalpurush`.