# Text formatting not working in Bangla text

Tags: punctuation, bold, italic

**Issue 1:**
With the reference of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620546/243840), I am using `babel` for writing Bangla text in *Lualatx*. But it show no দাঁড়ি চিহ্ন `(।)` which is a equivalent of full stop `(.)` in English. Here is a snippet of the output and দাঁড়ি চিহ্ন `(।)`    is expected in place of red sign. How can I solve the problem of full stop in Bangla text?

[image]

**Issue 2:**
Another problem is that **bold** and *italic* text formatting is not working here. How can I acheive this?

My working MWE is given:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}

\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Kalpurush}    

\begin{document}

\maketitle

গত বছর করোনা মহামারির তীব্র প্রকোপ সবচেয়ে সফলভাবে মোকাবিলা করতে পেরেছিল এশিয়ার দুই দেশ চীন ও দক্ষিণ কোরিয়া। \textbf{তাদের এ সাফল্যে এসেছিল মূলত দ্রুত সরকারি প্রতিক্রিয়ার পাশাপাশি উন্নত নাগরিক সহযোগিতার মাধ্যমে।} সরকারি কঠোর বিধিনিষেধ সহজভাবে মেনে চলেছে মানুষ। তবে সেই তুলনায় জাপান খুব ভালো প্রতিক্রিয়া দেখায়নি। \textit{সরকারি নীতিরও যথেষ্ট ফাঁকফোকর ছিল। ফলে করোনা মোকাবিলায় সেভাবে সফল নয় দেশটি।}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works if you explicitly set the language with `\selectlanguage{bengali}`. Without it babel switches back to the english font for your full stop, and this font doesn't have the char. It looks a bit like a bug to me, and I would suggest that you open an issue at the babel bug tracker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** In Unicode, danda is shared by several scripts, and `babel` doesn’t assign it by default to any of them. But you can assign it by hand:

```
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}
```

**2.** As far as I know, Kalpurush has neither bold nor italic variants.

Comment: it is imho a bit odd that the "danda" switches font then, shouldn't it simply use the current font if it isn't assigned to a specific script?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is a possible rule, but not the only one. Switching to the main font is also a legitimate option, and consistent with the behavior of the period, comma, colon, etc., which are also shared. We cannot know on beforehand every possible switch for all contexts and for all ‘shared’ characters.

Comment: Marcel and me discussed that in connection with the multiscript option of luaotfload. There is even an example in the documentation demonstrating some of the problems. But on the whole I prefer the rule that they follow the current script, or perhaps there should be an option which allows to set this rule.

Comment: `@Javier Bezos` Which font should I use instead of *Kalpurush* keeping similar font face (for Bold and italic face)?